# Install LAMP Stack into Virtual Environment

Tags: php, python, mysql, virtualenv, lamp

I want to isolate my LAMP installment into a virtual environment, I tried using virtualbox but my 4GB of RAM is not helping. My question is if I run sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ while in "venv"... would it install the mysql-server, apache2 and PHP into the virtualenv only or is the installation scope system-wide.

I really want a good solution for isolating these dev environments and their dependencies, and am hence exploring simple and efficient options given my system constraints. I have another Django (and mysql and gcloud) solution on the same computer and would like for these new installations to not mess with this.

I'm using:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Python: 2.7

Comment: Unfortunately, virtualenv is just available to python modules and LAMP it isn't.
Nowadays, the best way to isolate services is using docker,
Once you'll learn about docker, try to use docker-compose to connect the different isolated services.
There are a lot of tutorials and a bunch of examples on Github.
Enjoy!

Comment: Great tip! Docker seems like exactly what I was looking for, though I am a bit surprised that there is no Ubuntu package with this functionality!.

Comment: docker, (now) is multiplatform! so you can just download or install docker in your machine.

Comment: Any thoughts on lxd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualEnv is only for Python. If you want something "similar" to VirtualEnv (which is basically just a local installation of python, not a full virtualized system), then check out https://docker.com/ or other similar "containerization" solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's what I need.

Comment: Yep, have checked out Docker and have it running on my system. It serves my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Docker if You want make separate environments without virtual machine.

Comment: Awesome, checking out Docker now!